# Midpoint rule integral

Tags: calculus

I need to use the midpoint rule to approximate the area of ​​the following function $ f(x)= x^2+4x$ on the interval $[1,4]$ and I am confused how to use the formule, I know that  $ x_i= a+i\Delta x \\$

$ x_i=1+\dfrac{3i}{n}$

What is $ x_{i+1}$ or $x_{i-1}$?

Comment: $x_{i+1} = x_i + \Delta x = x_i + \frac {3}{n} = 1+\frac {3(i+1)}{n}$

Comment: I think you can't start at 1 and get midpoints. With your $x_i=1+3i/n,$ you get for $i=n$ that $x_n=4,$ not a midpoint but the right endpoint of the last subinterval.